# CUDA assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, cuda

Disassembling CUDA code appears to be a very useful tool, if not the only one in some cases, to understand the behaviour of the compiler as well as of performance metrics.

I would say that unfortunately the documentation available through the CUDA BINARY UTILITIES Application Note does not provide the user with all the tools needed to interpret CUDA assembly instructions or at least I'm not able to infer all the needed information from that document. The "CUDA Handbook" book does not provide any more information than the CUDA BINARY UTILITIES guide. For example, how should I interpret the instructions

```
ISETP.LT.AND P0, PT, R3, RZ, PT;
```

and

```
PSETP.AND.AND P0, PT, !P0, PT, PT;
```

What does `@P0` do before an instruction? Is it an instruction label so that the execution jumps to that label if the predicate register `P0` is true? Is there any general way to interpret the CUDA assembly instructions?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT FOLLOWING NJUFFA'S COMMENT**

I have compiled the following simple kernel

```
__global__ void test_kernel(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if ((tid > 5) && (tid < 10)) a[tid] = tid;
    else b[tid] = tid;
}
```

which resulted in

```
/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                 /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
/*0008*/        S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                    /* 0x2c00000094001c04 */
/*0010*/        S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                      /* 0x2c00000084009c04 */
/*0018*/        IMAD R2, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;          /* 0x2004400020009ca3 */
/*0020*/        IADD R0, R2, -0x6;                     /* 0x4800ffffe8201c03 */
/*0028*/        ISETP.LT.U32.AND P0, PT, R0, 0x4, PT;  /* 0x188ec0001001dc03 */
/*0030*/        I2F.F32.S32 R0, R2;                    /* 0x1800000009201e04 */
/*0038*/   @!P0 ISCADD R3, R2, c[0x0][0x24], 0x2;      /* 0x400040009020e043 */
/*0040*/    @P0 ISCADD R2, R2, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2;      /* 0x4000400080208043 */
/*0048*/   @!P0 ST [R3], R0;                           /* 0x9000000000302085 */
/*0050*/    @P0 ST [R2], R0;                           /* 0x9000000000200085 */
/*0058*/        EXIT ;                                 /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
```

The compiler has recast the condition `((tid > 5) && (tid < 10))` into `((i < 4) && (i >= 0))`, with `i = tid - 6`, so that the involved instruction is now

```
ISETP.LT.U32.AND P0, PT, R0, 0x4, PT;
```

Comment: The @Px and @!Px decorators (I think) denote conditional execution of a given instruction. That doesn't include branching

Comment: @talonmies Thanks. This is also my understanding. I agree that there is no jump, but only conditional execution.

Comment: I have a guess on the first instruction. Perhaps `PT` is a sort of delimiter. The instruction comes always (from what I have found on the internet) according to the structure, namely `ISETP.LT.AND P0, PT, Op1, Op2, PT;`. In the above case, it is simply implementing `R3<RZ` and storing the result of the comparison in `P0`. I know such an instruction should implement `R3<0`, so perhaps `RZ` is a special register containing `0`. Of course, it is just a guess.

Comment: I know there is no one-to-one mapping between PTX and disassebled code, but perhaps PTX could help understanding what happens in the latter. The PTX instructions corresponding to the first of the above assembly instructions is `setp.lt.s32 %p1, %r1, 0;` which puts in the predicate register `p1` the result of `r1<0`.

Comment: Concerning the `PSETP.AND.AND P0, PT, !P0, PT, PT;` instruction, it is apparently putting `!P0` in `P0`. The corresponding PTX instruction is `not.pred %p2, %p1;` which should put `!p1` into `p2`. The remaining `PT`'s are delimiters or a sort of neutral commands to fill operand positions.

Comment: @P0 before an instruction conditionally executes the instruction if predicate 0 is true. This is also used for conditional branching, i.e. a predicated BRA instruction. ISETP is an integer comparison with a predicate as a result. It allows chaining of predicates which is useful for compound branches. In this case, the chaining operator is AND: the generated predicate is chained with PT (= true). Try something like `if ((i > 5) && (i < 10))` to see the chaining between ISETPs. I am not sure why there are two instances of PT, though. Your interpretation of the PSETP seems correct to me.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for your comment. I have done the test you suggested and it seems that the compiler has recast the condition `((tid > 5) & (tid < 10))` into `((i < 4) & (i >= 0))`, with `i = tid - 6`, so that the involved instruction is now `ISETP.LT.U32.AND P0, PT, R0, 0x4, PT;`. If you will convert your comment to a full answer, it will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@P0` before an instruction conditionally executes the instruction if predicate register 0 is true. Likewise, `@!P0` before an instructions means the instruction is conditionally executed if predicate register 0 is false. When disassembling more complex machine code, you will see that there are typically multiple predicate registers in use. This predication mechanism is also used for conditional branching, by predicating the `BRA` instruction.

`ISETP` is an integer comparison (here: `LT` = less than) with the result written to a predicate register. It allows for chaining of predicates which is useful for compound branches. In your example chaining is not used since the compiler used a clever transformation that allows the compound condition to be evaluated with a single `ISETP`. Here, the chaining operator is `AND`, and the predicate generated by `ISETP` is chained with `PT` (= true). I am not sure what the significance of the second instance of `PT` is, you could probably find out by examining additional usage examples.

`PSETP` works along similar lines as `ISETP`, but works on predicates rather than integers. I have not had a need to look at this instruction closely, as it does not seem to occur very often. From what I can tell, `PSETP` combines two predicate registers and stores the result to a predicate register. Here it combines `!P0` and `PT` (= true) via `AND`. It seems that this instruction also supports chaining, in this case using `AND` to chain with `PT`. Your interpretation that your example represents a logical negation `P0 = !P0` seems correct. As in the case of `ISETP`, I am not sure what the meaning of the third `PT` could be.

Comment: Maybe the third `PT/P0` means whether the chain ends as [this nvidia topic comment](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-sass-question/62334/4) says "The second and third ISET are chained" (coincidently, it is also answered by njuffa). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @zgc I use the same account name (njuffa) here and on the NVIDIA forums. Whatever you see written here and there is the extent of my knowledge at that time, and I have not acquired any new knowledge regarding predicate handling since then, as I did not have a need to get deeper into the deciphering of the operations.